# JMeter - are there any Summary Reports out there that facets on Sub-Result labels?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter report with sub-results.

```
  [Request 1]
    [SubResult A]
    [SubResult B]
    [SubResult C]
```

When we look at the JMeter Summary Report, it only facets on the main request label.

Are there any out-of-box jmeter reports that do sub-result faceting? Or will I have to build it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener does:

[image]

There are also entries for the sub-results in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

By default JMeter includes the "sub results" elapsed time into "main" request elapsed time, exposing them as individual requests might cause problems with calculation of [KPIs](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis) like average response time, throughput, etc. so if you will go for "build myself" please consider this

Comment: yeah we already use the View Results Tree which is great for looking at the responses but has no statistics. i'm taking your answer as "there is no summary report with sub-results, and if you build it, here is what to look out for" so i accepted your answer